# Submitting Form and getting data from fields/radio/checkbox/textareas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I have created a form and I am looking to get the data the user entered. 
The javascript I have so far pulls in all the data. But also pulls both radio buttons although only one is checked.

**Q1** How do I restrict the loop to not pull in both radio buttons but only the selected one?

**Q2** How do I get if the check box is checked or not?

**Q3** How do I get the data from a `textarea`?

Thanks in Advance,

**JS**

```
var myNodeList = document.getElementsByName('cf');
var myArray = []; // empty Array
for (var i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
    var self = myNodeList[i];
    myArray.push(self);
}
console.log(myArray)
```

**HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact Me</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contactform_Lab8.css">
</head>

<body>

<form id="contactus">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="cf" autofocus required>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="cf" required>
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input id="phone" type="tel" name="cf" required>
        <label for="status">Status:         
            <select id="status" name="cf" required>
                <option value="client">Client</option>
                <option value="partner">Partner</option>
                <option value="vendor">Vendor</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label for="subscribe">
            <input id="subscribe" type="checkbox" name="cf" value="check" checked> 
        Send me your newsletter</label>
        <label for="sales">
            <label for="support">
                <input id="slsSupport" type="radio" name="cf" value="sales" checked>Sales
                <input id="slsSupport" type="radio" name="cf" value="support">Support
            </label>
        </label>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="msg" name="cf" rows="10" cols="30" required></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        </fieldset>
</form>
<script src="contactform_Lab8.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Use the [checked property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp) on the element, and if it's not checked, advance to the next element.

Q2: See question #1

Q3: `document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML;`

Comment: How can can I just get the data without all the properties? Such as when pulling in the name how can I just get the name. This works but how can I get the values of my other inputs? `myArray.push(document.getElementById('status').value)` @Danbopes

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an If statement to check the type of the element.

```
   if(self.type === "radio" && self.checked){
        myArray.push(self);      
    }
    if(self.type !== "radio"){
        myArray.push(self);
    }
```